# Count value in js object

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

I have an object of who are coming to the event

```
{ "Ann": true, "Billy": false, "Cat": false, "David": true }
```

How can I count the number of people is attending?

object.values.length to get the total number of people

Comment: court?? Do you mean count?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Object.values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Here the idea is

- First get all the values from object.
- Using reduce we sum up values.

```js
let obj = { "Ann": true, "Billy": false, "Cat": false, "David": true }

let count = Object.values(obj).reduce((op,inp) => op + inp , 0)

console.log(count)
```

Comment: Would you explain what are `(op,inp)=>op+(+inp),0` ?

Comment: @susuwatari it's arrow function with implicit return. it just add value to `op` and return `op`. notice here `(+inp)` is used for `boolean` to `digit` conversion

Comment: @susuwatari there are several more ways of conversion from boolean to digits such as `Number` or `~~boolean` or `+` etc.

Answer (score 1):

> object.values.length to get the total number of people

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out `false` values:

```js
const obj = {"Ann": true, "Billy": false, "Cat": false,"David": true};
console.log(
  Object.values(obj).filter(Boolean).length
);
```

If you want to get the names of people who are attending you can do something like this:

```js
const obj = {"Ann": true, "Billy": false, "Cat": false,"David": true};

const attendees = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(entry => entry[1])
  .map(entry => entry[0]);

console.log(attendees);
console.log(attendees.length);
```

Comment: On side note: In your second example i think `reduce` is better option than using filter and than map

Answer (score 0):

In modern environments, you can use a `for-of` loop on the array returned by `Object.values`:

```
let sum = 0;
for (const flag of Object.values(yourObject)) {
    if (flag) {
        ++sum;
    }
}
```

```js
const yourObject = { "Ann": true, "Billy": false, "Cat": false, "David": true };
let sum = 0;
for (const flag of Object.values(yourObject)) {
    if (flag) {
        ++sum;
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

or `reduce` on it:

```
const sum = Object.values(yourObject).reduce((sum, flag) => sum + (flag ? 1 : 0), 0);
```

```js
const yourObject = { "Ann": true, "Billy": false, "Cat": false, "David": true };
const sum = Object.values(yourObject).reduce((sum, flag) => sum + (flag ? 1 : 0), 0);
console.log(sum);
```

In older environments, you can use `for-in`:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var key in yourObject) {
    if (yourObject[key]) {
        ++sum;
    }
}
```

```js
var yourObject = { "Ann": true, "Billy": false, "Cat": false, "David": true };
var sum = 0;
for (var key in yourObject) {
    if (yourObject[key]) {
        ++sum;
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it many ways. Here is one with filter...

```
let obj = { "Ann": true, "Billy": false, "Cat": false, "David": true }   
Object.values(obj).filter( person => person === true).length
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the boolean value who is coerced to a number.

```js
var object = { Ann: true, Billy: false, Cat: false, David: true },
    count = Object.values(object).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(count);
```

Comment: why down-voted? seems to be best answer, no need of typecasting using + addition already does the work. +1
However no need to pass the initial value, loop will start from 1 and take 0th as initial value.